# Perform summation at indizes saved as x and y arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, indexing, vectorization

I have basic question regarding indexing. I have two array lists with len = 9mio encoding vectorized image coordinates that have been extracted via computation by a previous function. Now I want to decrease a heatmap using the vectorized data. I could use a for loop and zip the coordinates. However, I would prefer a faster solution like

```
T = [L[i] +=1 for i in zip(X,Y)]
```

or something. Is this possible?

```
coord = [x_coords,y_coords]
Heatmap[coord[0],coord[1]] -= 1
```

Comment: What are array lists? 1D numpy arrays? And  your heatmap is a 2D numpy array? Or is it a list of lists? It might be good to include a toy data set in the question.

Comment: Heatmap is a 1D zero np array with the size of the input image flattened. And x_coord is a list with 9kk entries so is y_coord. Can also change the type of x_coord to np array if its better

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution using `collections`. I have also added performance comparison versus [@Piinthesky's `pandas` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48662969/9209546).

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

#your pre-existing heatmap as a numpy array
heat_map = np.arange(32).reshape(8, 4)

#your x and y pairs as lists
x = [2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 3]
y = [3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1]

def jp_data_analysis(heat_map, x, y):

    #count occurences of x, y pairs
    c = OrderedDict(Counter(zip(x, y)))

    #create numpy array with count as value at position x, y
    x_c, y_c = list(zip(*c))
    pic_occur[x_c, y_c] = list(c.values())

    #subtract this from heatmap
    heat_map -= pic_occur

    return heat_map

def piinthesky(heat_map, x, y):

    #count occurences of x, y pairs
    df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y}).groupby(["x", "y"]).size().reset_index(name='count')

    #create numpy array with count as value at position x, y
    pic_occur = np.zeros([heat_map.shape[0], heat_map.shape[1]], dtype = int)
    pic_occur[df["x"], df["y"]] = df["count"]

    #and subtract this from heatmap
    heat_map -= pic_occur

    return heat_map


%timeit jp_data_analysis(heat_map, x, y)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 43.8 µs per loop

%timeit piinthesky(heat_map, x, y)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.45 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I made a mistake in my calculations of the coordinates in the step before int(i + gp[0] + radius),int(j + gp[1] + radius) which means I nead my indizes separated into 2D coordinates not 1D.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using numpy/pandas. The x, y convention is according to the usual connotation in pictures, but you better check this with your dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
#your pre-existing heatmap as a numpy array
heat_map = np.arange(32).reshape(8, 4)

#your x and y pairs as lists
x = [2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 3]
y = [3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1]

#count occurences of x, y pairs
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y}).groupby(["x", "y"]).size().reset_index(name='count')
#create numpy array with count as value at position x, y
pic_occur = np.zeros([heat_map.shape[0], heat_map.shape[1]], dtype = int)
pic_occur[df["x"], df["y"]] = df["count"]
#and subtract this from heatmap
heat_map -= pic_occur
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I made a mistake in my calculations of the coordinates in the step before int(i + gp[0] + radius),int(j + gp[1] + radius) which means I nead my indizes separated into 2D coordinates not 1D.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I made a mistake in my calculations of the coordinates in the step before int(i + gp[0] + radius),int(j + gp[1] + radius) which means I nead my indizes separated into 2D coordinates not 1D.